# Parsing XML data in C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have a xml data like this

```
string data = @"<DeliveryReport><message id=""093102403501103726"" 
    sentdate=""2013/10/24 08:50:11"" donedate=""2013/10/24 08:50:12""
    status=""NOT_DELIVERED"" gsmerror=""1"" /></DeliveryReport>";
```

and am converting/parsing it like

```
if (data != null)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(data);

    var tutorials = from tutorial in xmlDoc.Descendants("message")
        select new
        {

        };
}
```

is is throwing error **Illegal characters in path.** can any body tell me what i m misisng?

Comment: @SteveB: It's not a duplicate of that - one was using the `XmlTextReader` constructor, this is using `XDocument.Load`. Sure, it's the same idea of "you've provided text to a method accepting a filename/URI" but the best solution is somewhat different.

Comment: @SteveB: Right - that's definitely a duplicate. Although I prefer my answer here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`XDocument.Load(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx), which accepts a filename or URL to load the XML from:

> **Parameters**
>   *uri*: A URI string that references the file to load into a new XDocument.

You want [`XDocument.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx), which accepts XML already in a string:

> **Parameters**
>   *text*: A string that contains XML.

Comment: What's the difference between this and LoadXML?

Comment: @Jerry: LoadXML is in XmlDocument, not XDocument.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I haven't used XDocument before. Is it better than XmlDocument?

Comment: @Jerry: Yes, LINQ to XML is a *much* cleaner API than the old XmlDocument one. It's well worth learning about.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `TextReader` overload of `Load` when you create your `XDocument`:

```
if (data != null)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(data));

    var tutorials = from tutorial in xmlDoc.Descendants("message")
                    select new
                    {

                    };

}
```

Comment: Why bother with that when XDocument.Parse handles it already?

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't aware of parse actually. I always use the `TextReader` overload for my XDocuments - mainly because they are either a) from file or b) stackoverflow answers that originally used a stream.

Comment: If they're from a stream, I'd use `XDocument.Load(Stream)` which allows the parser to autodetect the encoding - safer than doing that twice...

Comment: @JonSkeet Noted sir. Thanks for the input. Every day is a school day.